# Save and Restore your Terminal tabs

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal

I have a large list of tabs which are open in each terminal. I'd need to save them with a meaningful name and restore later when I need them.
From what I've checked in another thread you could use:
gnome-terminal --save-config
However in my gnome-terminal:

```
$ gnome-terminal --save-config=/tmp/cfg
Option "--save-config" is no longer supported in this version of gnome-terminal.

$ gnome-terminal --version
GNOME Terminal 3.22.1 Using VTE version 0.46.1 +GNUTLS
```

Any other option available?

Comment: Yes it's a pity they removed the `save-config` option. I have somehow managed to work around this using various tricks including `xdotool`, see for example [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/606235/156688) answer.

Comment: The other post does have some more recent answers, though it seems there's no longer a simple way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

options like `--save-config --load-config` really worked in previous versions of gnome-terminal (for example default one in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS).
But not anymore. On 16.04 default version is GNOME Terminal 3.18.3 which already has such options removed.
Seems like the solution could be build an older version or switch to another terminal program.